# ZF2 with PhlyRestfully The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request

Tags: api, rest, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use [PhlyRestfully](https://github.com/weierophinney/PhlyRestfully) module to build an API with Zend Framework 2. The issue is that although I have a correct configuration, the ResourceController fails to dispatch to the Resource. This is what I get as a response:

```
The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.

Controller:
Api\Controller\Locations

No Exception available
```

I will describe my configuration below:

application.php

```
'modules' => array(
    'PhlyRestfully',
    'Api',
    'Application',
)
```

Api/config/module.config.php

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'api' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/api',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Api\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'locations' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/locations[/[:id]]',
                            'controller' => 'Api\Controller\Locations',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Api\Controller\Locations'
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy'
        ),
    ),
    'phlyrestfully' => array(
        'resources' => array(
            'Api\Controller\Locations' => array(
                'listener' => 'Api\Resource\Location',
                'route_name' => 'api/locations'
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Api/Resource/Location.php

```
namespace Api\Resource;

class Location extends AbstractListenerAggregate
{
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('fetch', array($this, 'onFetch'));
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('fetchAll', array($this, 'onFetchAll'));
    }

    public function onFetchAll(ResourceEvent $e)
    {
        var_dump($e);
    }

    public function onFetch(ResourceEvent $e)
    {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

I have omitted some uses and other lines that are not essential for brevity.

URL: /api/locations

The routing works fine, as the ResourceController is called and injected with the appropriate Resource. The attach() method on the Listener is invoked, but instead of the events being fired by the Resource, the onDispatch method of the AbstractRestfulController is called and it returns 404 since I did not actually define a LocationsController with an indexAction.

It is my understanding that PhlyRestfully emulates the existence of these resource controllers through the provided ResourceController and you don't need to actually create these controller classes, as this is the whole point of the module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the default action in your route config.

Comment: Additionally, if your REST route is a child of another route that requires a default action, then you can set your REST default action to `null` instead of removing it altogether

Answer (score 2):

And exactly this error happen to me when I forgot the  `Action`  suffix of my method in my controller.